# Prove $(F+G)+H=F+(G+H)$

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm wondering it appears simple but how could we prove :

Let $F,G,H$ be three subvector spaces of $E$, prove that $(F+G)+H=F+(G+H)$

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by $+$ here? Is $F+G = \{f+g:f\in F,g\in G\}$? If so, it follows from associativity of vector addition..

Answer (score 1):

We have $F+G=\{f+g\mid f\in F,g\in G\}$, so for all $f+g\in F+G$ and all $h\in H$,
$$\left(f+g\right)+h=f+\left(g+h\right)\in F+\left(G+H\right)$$
so $\left(F+G\right)+H\subset F+\left(G+H\right)$. Do the same for the inverse inclusion to have the equality.